# Understanding accessors and mutators in Python

Tags: python, accessor, mutators

i want to know how do we call the "del" method in this case, the getter and setter ones are shown, but no the deletion one. Thank you. (Taken from geeksforgeeks)

```
class Geeks: 
     def __init__(self): 
          self._age = 0

     # function to get value of _age 
     def get_age(self): 
         print("getter method called") 
         return self._age 

     # function to set value of _age 
     def set_age(self, a): 
         print("setter method called") 
         self._age = a 

     # function to delete _age attribute 
     def del_age(self): 
         del self._age 

     age = property(get_age, set_age, del_age)  

mark = Geeks() 

mark.age = 10

print(mark.age)
```

Answer (score 1):

The deleter is invoked by using the `del` statement on the property: `del mark.age`.

Comment: Thank you very much, it was driving me crazy typing object.__del__().